# Event Trigger Ode's

Tags: differential-equations, control-systems, event-detection

I am trying to simulate a Hybrid system using the `WhenEvent` function in Mathematica. I have asked this question [earlier](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/178588/event-triggered-odes). It was not an MWE. Now I tried to make an MWE.

Parameter generation:

```
Np = 4;
classes = 2;
Xa = RandomReal[{1, 2}, {2, 2}];
Xb = RandomReal[{3, 4}, {2, 2}];
Plotxa = ListPlot[Xa, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Black}];
Plotxb = ListPlot[Xb, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red}];
Plotx = Show[Plotxa, Plotxb, PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {0, 5}}]
X = Join[Xa, Xb];
Xex = X /. {a_, b_} -> {1, a, b}
y = ConstantArray[1, 2]; yb = ConstantArray[-1, 2];
Y = Join[y, yb];
```

Below code generates the differential equations in symbolic form

```
β = 
  Join[{β0[t]}, Array[Symbol["β" <> ToString@#][t] &, 2]];
μ = Array[Symbol["μ" <> ToString@#][t] &, 4];
var = Join[β, μ]
varInit = var /. {t -> 0};
g = (1 - (Xex.β)*Y)
L = Total[g*μ] + 1/2 (β1[t]^2 + β2[t]^2);
f = Join[-D[L, {β}], D[L, {μ}]];
```

Finally the ODE simulation

```
DAE = {Thread[D[var, t] == f], 
   Thread[varInit == Flatten[RandomReal[{1, 2}, {1, 7}]]], 
   WhenEvent[μ1[t] == 
      0 && (1 - β0[t] - 1.0277165069495682` β1[t] - 
        1.3523023083294536` β2[t]) <= 0, 
    Derivative[1][μ1][t] -> 0]} // Flatten
sol = NDSolve[DAE, var, {t, 0, 100000}, MaxSteps -> 10000000, 
  AccuracyGoal -> 5, 
  Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}]
```

In the DAE, I have the WhenEvent function. I was trying to model the following

$$\begin{eqnarray}
\dot \mu_i&=&\left\{\begin{matrix}
0 ; &\;    if\;\; \mu_i(t)=0\;\;\text{and }\;1-\beta(t)^\top x\leq0\\
 1-\beta(t)^\top x ;&\; else
\end{matrix} \right. 
\end{eqnarray}$$

Where $x\in Xex$ set defined in the line `Xex = X /. {a_, b_} -> {1, a, b}`. Moreover I need to write 4 conditions as ($i\in \{1...4\}$), as a test case I was checking for just $i=1$.

From my simulation, I could see that the `WhenEvent` function is not working.

FYI: I added `AccuracyGoal -> 5, Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}` because Mathematica forced me to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved the problem without using `WithEvent` function but using `If` function. I thought I will share the solution.

```
Np = 4;
classes = 2;
eps = 0.01;
Xa = RandomReal[{1, 2}, {2, 2}];
Xb = RandomReal[{3, 4}, {2, 2}];
Plotxa = ListPlot[Xa, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Black}];
Plotxb = ListPlot[Xb, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red}];
Plotx = Show[Plotxa, Plotxb, PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {0, 5}}]
X = Join[Xa, Xb];
Xex = X /. {a_, b_} -> {1, a, b};
y = ConstantArray[1, 2]; yb = ConstantArray[-1, 2];
Y = Join[y, yb];
x = Array[Symbol["x" <> ToString@#] &, 4];
y = Array[Symbol["y" <> ToString@#] &, 4];
\[Beta] = 
  Join[{\[Beta]0[t]}, Array[Symbol["\[Beta]" <> ToString@#][t] &, 2]];
\[Mu] = Array[Symbol["\[Mu]" <> ToString@#][t] &, 4];
var = Join[\[Beta], \[Mu]]
varInit = var /. {t -> 0};
g = (1 - (Xex.\[Beta])*Y);
Cond = Thread[Thread[\[Mu] <= eps] && Thread[g <= eps]];
fmu = Transpose[{Cond, g}] /. {a_, b_} -> {If[a, 0, b]};
L = Total[g*\[Mu]] + 1/2 (\[Beta]1[t]^2 + \[Beta]2[t]^2);
f = Join[-D[L, {\[Beta]}], fmu] //  Flatten; MatrixForm[f]
opts = {Method -> {"TimeIntegration" -> {"ExplicitRungeKutta", 
       "DifferenceOrder" -> 7}}};
DAE = {Thread[D[var, t] == f], 
   Thread[varInit == Flatten[RandomReal[{100, 200}, {1, 7}]]]} // 
  Flatten; MatrixForm[DAE]
sol = NDSolve[DAE, var, {t, 0, 100000}, MaxSteps -> 10000000, 
  AccuracyGoal -> 5, 
  Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}]
```

If someone is interested, the solution of the problem is actually an SVM (linear case).

```
Plot[Evaluate[(1 - (Xex.\[Beta])*Y) /. First[sol]], {t, 0, 300}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue, Green, Orange, Black}]
Plot[Evaluate[{\[Mu]1[t], \[Mu]2[t], \[Mu]3[t], \[Mu]4[t]} /. 
   First[sol]], {t, 0, 300}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue, Green, Orange}]
Plot[Evaluate[{\[Beta]0[t], \[Beta]1[t], \[Beta]2[t]} /. 
   First[sol]], {t, 0, 300}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue, Green}]
Plotxa = ListPlot[Xa, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Black}];
Plotxb = ListPlot[Xb, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red}];
Plotsvm = 
  Plot[-(1/\[Beta]2[t])*(\[Beta]1[t]*x + \[Beta]0[t]) /. 
     First[sol] /. {t -> 100000}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}];
Plotx = Show[Plotxa, Plotxb, Plotsvm, PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {0, 5}}]
```

[image]